# Evaluating the combined values of multiple columns, possibly with dplyr

Tags: r

I know this question has been asked, but I can't remember which search terms to use to find it. I have a data frame and want to produce a new column based on an evaluation of the values in some of the other columns. For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  name    = c("ann",       "bob",       "cam",        "dan",       "eve"), 
  A_param = c("down",      "unchanged", "up",         "unchanged", "up"),
  B_param = c("down",      "down",      "unchanged",  "unchanged", "up"),
  C_param = c("unchanged", "up",        "up",         "unchanged", "down")
)
```

I want to evaluate whether each person's parameters were monotonic (e.g. always "up" or "unchanged", or always "down" or "unchanged"). I think this can be done using `across` and `case_when`, but I keep getting errors. I have tried the following:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    monotonic = dplyr::case_when(
      unique(sort(dplyr::across(ends_with("param")))) == 
                             c("down")                    ~ "down",
      unique(sort(dplyr::across(ends_with("param")))) == 
                             c("unchanged")               ~ "static",
      unique(sort(dplyr::across(ends_with("param")))) == 
                             c("up")                      ~ "up",
      unique(sort(dplyr::across(ends_with("param")))) == 
                             c("down", "unchanged")       ~ "down",
      unique(sort(dplyr::across(ends_with("param")))) ==
                             c("down", "up")              ~ "non",
      unique(sort(dplyr::across(ends_with("param")))) == 
                             c("unchanged", "up")         ~ "up",
      unique(sort(dplyr::across(ends_with("param")))) == 
                             c("down", "unchanged", "up") ~ "non", 
      TRUE                                                ~ "error"
     )
  )
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `monotonic`.
i `monotonic = dplyr::case_when(...)`.
x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Locations 6, 7, 15, 4, 8, etc. don't exist.
i There are only 3 columns.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
x
+-<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
| Problem with `mutate()` column `monotonic`.
| i `monotonic = dplyr::case_when(...)`.
| x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
| x Locations 6, 7, 15, 4, 8, etc. don't exist.
| i There are only 3 columns.
\-<error/vctrs_error_subscript_oob>
  Can't subset columns that don't exist.
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
 11. base::sort.default(dplyr::across(ends_with("param")))
 13. tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing))
 14. tibble:::vectbl_as_col_location(...)
 17. vctrs::vec_as_location(j, n, names)
 19. vctrs:::stop_subscript_oob(...)
 20. vctrs:::stop_subscript(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
x
+-<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
| Problem with `mutate()` column `monotonic`.
| i `monotonic = dplyr::case_when(...)`.
| x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
| x Locations 6, 7, 15, 4, 8, etc. don't exist.
| i There are only 3 columns.
\-<error/vctrs_error_subscript_oob>
  Can't subset columns that don't exist.
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-`%>%`(...)
  2. +-dplyr::mutate(...)
  3. +-dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
  4. | \-dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ..., caller_env = caller_env())
  5. |   +-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  6. |   \-mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
  7. +-dplyr::case_when(...)
  8. | \-rlang::eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env)
  9. +-base::unique(sort(dplyr::across(ends_with("param"))))
 10. +-base::sort(dplyr::across(ends_with("param")))
 11. \-base::sort.default(dplyr::across(ends_with("param")))
 12.   +-x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)]
 13.   \-tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing))
 14.     \-tibble:::vectbl_as_col_location(...)
 15.       +-tibble:::subclass_col_index_errors(...)
 16.       | \-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 17.       \-vctrs::vec_as_location(j, n, names)
 18.         \-(function () ...
 19.           \-vctrs:::stop_subscript_oob(...)
 20.             \-vctrs:::stop_subscript(...)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    monotonic = dplyr::case_when(
      unique(dplyr::across(ends_with("param"))) == 
        c("down")                    ~ "down",
      unique(dplyr::across(ends_with("param"))) == 
        c("unchanged")               ~ "static",
      unique(dplyr::across(ends_with("param"))) == 
        c("up")                      ~ "up",
      unique(dplyr::across(ends_with("param"))) == 
        c("down", "unchanged")       ~ "down",
      unique(dplyr::across(ends_with("param"))) ==
        c("down", "up")              ~ "non",
      unique(dplyr::across(ends_with("param"))) == 
        c("unchanged", "up")         ~ "up",
      unique(dplyr::across(ends_with("param"))) == 
        c("down", "unchanged", "up") ~ "non", 
      TRUE                           ~ "error"
    )
  )
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `monotonic`.
i `monotonic = dplyr::case_when(...)`.
i `monotonic` must be size 5 or 1, not 15.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.


df2 <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    monotonic = dplyr::case_when(
       dplyr::across(ends_with("param")) == 
                            c("down")                    ~ "down",
       dplyr::across(ends_with("param")) == 
                            c("unchanged")               ~ "static",
       dplyr::across(ends_with("param")) == 
                            c("up")                      ~ "up",
       dplyr::across(ends_with("param")) == 
                            c("down", "unchanged")       ~ "down",
       dplyr::across(ends_with("param")) ==
                            c("down", "up")              ~ "non",
       dplyr::across(ends_with("param")) == 
                            c("unchanged", "up")         ~ "up",
       dplyr::across(ends_with("param")) == 
                            c("down", "unchanged", "up") ~ "non", 
      TRUE                                               ~ "error"
    )
  )
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `monotonic`.
i `monotonic = dplyr::case_when(...)`.
i `monotonic` must be size 5 or 1, not 15.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The result of the code makes me think the problem is that `dplyr::across(ends_with("param"))` produces a 3x5 tibble, rather than the vectors required to evaluate the `case_when` comparisons:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    monotonic = dplyr::across(ends_with("param"))
  )
```

I think `dplyr::rowwise` may hold the answer, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: `c_across` may also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier if you get all the data in one column and then use `case_when` for different conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(combined = toString(sort(unique(c_across(ends_with('param')))))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(monotonic = case_when(combined == 'down' ~ 'down', 
                               combined == 'unchanged' ~ 'unchanged', 
                               combined == 'up' ~ 'up', 
                               combined == 'down, unchanged' ~ 'down', 
                               combined == 'down, up' ~ 'non', 
                               combined == 'unchanged, up' ~ 'up', 
                               combined == 'down, unchanged, up' ~ 'non-error')) %>%
  select(-combined)

#  name  A_param   B_param   C_param   monotonic
#  <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
#1 ann   down      down      unchanged down     
#2 bob   unchanged down      up        non-error
#3 cam   up        unchanged up        up       
#4 dan   unchanged unchanged unchanged unchanged
#5 eve   up        up        down      non
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
> df1 %>% mutate(monotonic=if_all(ends_with("param"), ~ .x %in% c("unchanged", "up")))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  name  A_param   B_param   C_param   monotonic
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <lgl>    
1 ann   down      down      unchanged FALSE    
2 bob   unchanged down      up        FALSE    
3 cam   up        unchanged up        TRUE     
4 dan   unchanged unchanged unchanged TRUE     
5 eve   up        up        down      FALSE
```

Comment: I also want to capture people who are always "down" or "unchanged", and differentiate these from the 'always "up" or "unchanged"' people. I have edited the OP for clarity on this point.